# t.replace is not a function(…)trim

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, leaflet

The following is producing the error in the question when I check in console.log and it breaks it

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);

<?php 
    $classesForCountries = [];
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $classesForCountries[ get_field('country') ] += get_field('year') + ' ';
    endwhile; endif;
?>

// Now this should look something like {"Australia": "2006 2010 "}

var classNameMap = <?php echo JSON_encode($classesForCountries); ?>;
geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {
    style: function(feature) {

        // Here is where we got the issue

        var classes = classNameMap[feature.properties.sovereignt];
        if (classes) {
            return {className: classes};
        }
    },
}).addTo(map);
```

**UPDATE**

by looking at console.log, it points me to a line in the library:

```
...t.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")},splitWords:function(t){return o.Util.trim(t).split(/\s+/)}...
```

Comment: Can't see `t.replace` anywhere in the code you have posted.

Comment: @void it's what the console says I am afraid, no idea why, not doing anything else than what you see above

Comment: Console should also indicate a  line number, which you should be able to match with a line in your code, or it may be in an included script/library

Comment: @trincot it does indeed come from the library, console says leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: t.replace is not a function(…)

Comment: What is your `map` variable right at the end? Did you define that variable at all?

Comment: @trincot yes that is how leafletjs works, updated the quetsion with the map var. These are the docs http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Comment: you are separating your js from php, right? and using script tags? question's unclear.

Comment: `+= get_field('year') + ' '` are you trying to do math here? If not, you're in php here, not js concatenation. So use dots not plus signs. `.= get_field('year') . ' '`

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol superb. Thanks a lot. Put that in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"@Fred-ii- lol superb. Thanks a lot. Put that in an answer and I will accept it. – rob.m"*

As per OP's request:

This `+= get_field('year') + ' '`

You may have come from a JS/C background and think that the `+` signs can be used for concatenation in PHP. PHP is interpreting the plus signs in thinking you want to do math.

It is the dots that concatenate in PHP:

```
.= get_field('year') . ' '
```